# MongoDB query: date range (but dates in collection are in NumberLong format)

Tags: mongodb, query

I need some help with my MongoDB query.
I was trying to count in collection the number of entries for a specific date (i.e. May 05, 2016), but dates in the collection are in NumberLong data type. So I did this query:

```
db.workerLog.find({$and:[{"startTime" : { $gte: NumberLong(1462377600000)}},
    {"completeTime" : { $lte: NumberLong(1462463999000)}}]}).count()
```

However, upon checking the results, the results set contain entries after May 05, 2016 (like May 06, 2016), such as this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("572c4cb5c497211b8ed9a91e"),
  "jobId" : "572c4cb4c497211b8ed9a91a",
  "resourceType" : "CHART",
  "resourceId" : "57281f1e45e91408a197a07f",
  "startTime" : NumberLong(1462521012014), -- this is Fri May 06 2016 15:50:12 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)
  "completeTime" : NumberLong(0),
  "source" : "itunes",
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: It looks like your sample document matches both query conditions, but perhaps isn't what you anticipated since  `completeTime` is `0`. If you are expecting  `startTime` to always be within your date range, the `$lte` condition should be on `startTime`. Otherwise you could add a condition on `completeTime` $gt 0.